# Use one big image for background or multiple ones in Cordova?

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building a Cordova app for both iOS and Android so naturally there are a lot of different screen sizes.

Some of my views have a full background image. My question is:

Is is better to use one big image that will cover the largest potential device and just use that for all devices, or use a lot of different images assigning each one to the right device using media queries?

Just looking for best practice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using an image that is 2732 x 2048 (largest iPad [screen size](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ipad%20pro%20screen%20size) today) combined with [cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), percentage, or [viewport](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) background css sizing. For example:

http://play.ionic.io/app/094f73be9047

css

```
ion-content {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Keeny-creek-wv-autumn-waterfall-scenery_-_West_Virginia_-_ForestWander.jpg);
  background-size: cover;

  text-align: center;
}

ion-content p {
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive" class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>I am so beautiful</p>
        <button class="button button-positive">I'm a button</button>
      </ion-content>

    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a way to use that image as pattern. Doing that you will not have issues with different screen sizes.